# Can I update JCLiteral in Javac plugin

Tags: java, plugins, compilation

I created a POC where I want to encrypt String constants in specific method calls at compile time.

I'm using a compiler plugin, used this page as starting point: [Baeldung - Build a Java compiler plugin](https://www.baeldung.com/java-build-compiler-plugin)
I was able to find the method calls (only in the ANALYZE phase), and I can even update the value of the JCTree.JCLiteral seemingly (printed the new value to console), but at the end the compiled classes are still containing the original values.

The core part of my code looks like this:

```
if (taskEvent.getKind() != TaskEvent.Kind.ANALYZE) {
    return;
}
taskEvent.getCompilationUnit().accept(new TreeScanner<Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void visitMethodInvocation(MethodInvocationTree invocationTree, Void unused) {

        if (isMethodToBeUpdated(invocationTree, env)) {
            System.out.println("Found usage: " + invocationTree);
            JCTree.JCMethodInvocation methodInvocation = (JCTree.JCMethodInvocation) invocationTree;

            JCTree.JCExpression firstParam = methodInvocation.getArguments().get(0);
            if (firstParam instanceof JCTree.JCLiteral) {
                ((JCTree.JCLiteral) firstParam).value = "...FOO...";
            }

            System.out.println("meth after: " + methodInvocation);
            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }
}, null);
```

Unfortunately this compiler plugin feature is very under documented. I tried to make the update in the PARSE phase, but there the called method's class (and its interface) is not available (or at least i couldn't query it).

Anybody has any experience how to implement the updating of the value the way it gets persisted into the compiled bytecode?

Basically I was expecting that if I update the value in the AST, and it is before the GENERATE phase, the bytecode is being generated using the updates AST. I even sout-ed the updated object, which was updated, but if I check the class file, it still contains the unchanged value.

Comment: Updates:
I must use an old version of JDK 8. The updating of the AST can be done by using TreeTranslator in the "started" method in the ANALYZE phase, but resolving the type of the variable is working only in the "finished" method in the ANALYZE. So it is doable, but finding the called type in the same round is probably not possible.